# "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app" in magento2

Tags: magento2, google-api, google

I keep getting error as shown in below link while creating new account through google sign. I verified the app but still not effect seen.

http://prntscr.com/q4vbg8

Also below given error is generated 
"Endpoint: Error while trying to init Hybrid_Auth: You cannot access this page directly."
How can i solve it ?